# React Scroll like page turn or scroll certain amount once time

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, nodes

How can I prevents default scrolling and automatically scroll to next item?

For an instance, I have element2 under element1, how can I scroll to element2 position when I scroll down once instead scroll a little bit down.

Or is there any way to scroll down one window/viewport height? Rather than scroll down arbitrary amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scrollIntoView to make the page scroll to particular element.

```
componentDidMount(){ 
   window.addEventListener('scroll',()=> {
            if (this.state.scroll) {
               document.getElementById("element").scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
            }
        })
     } 
handleClick(){
  document.getElementById("element").scrollIntoView(true)
}
render(){
  return (
     <div>
       <element1 onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}></element1>
       <element2 id="element"></element2>
     </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: where should I call handleClick() function? I do not want any button. I just need it will automatically scroll to element when I scroll.

Comment: Should I use handleScroll instead of handleClick and onWheel={(e) => this.handleScroll(e)?

Comment: I have changed my answer.I assume it should be a element like button to trigger the scroll function.

Comment: And you can also add scrollIntoView in componentDidMount.In this circumstance ,you should add something like this.state.scroll to control the scroll function.If not ,the page will continually to scroll to the particular element.